# how to Fetch data from database in magento

Tags: database, mysql, data

Which methods are available for fetching information from the Magento database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You essentially have three methods in which to do so:

**1. Using the [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) (ref: [Magento Example Summary](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics))**

Depending on the type of information you need, you can use Magento's native `Mage::` calls to fetch data from products, categories, customers, orders etc.

E.g. `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id)->getName();` will fetch the product name from the database.

**2. Using direct SQL**

You can easily instantiate a connection object and access information from the databse using direct SQL queries. E.g:

```
$connection = Mage::getModel('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_order`';
$orders = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

**3. Using database management tools**

You can access the information via GUI using a wide array of services. E.G:

- phpMyAdmin,
- Navicat etc.